# Wrong order in Chart.js graph with time on the X-Axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello Im trying to plot some data on angularjs using chart.js , but Im getting a weird ordering of my data, which results in a weird chart like this:

[image]

This are my options:

```
 vm.options = {
        type:'line',
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            position: 'bottom'
          }]
        }
      };
```

I tried ordering the date of my data like this:

```
    vm.data.sort(function(a,b){
      // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
      // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
      return new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time);
    });
```

But the result is the image above. Can anyone help me spot the problem?

Comment: post a fiddle with same problem

Comment: Did you try swapping a and b? `return new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time);`

Answer (score 0):

Though it is an old post but I am answering so that somebody may get benefit from it!

I have faced similar problem with my ionic3 app. I had a problematic graph with wrong order,though my dataset was in right order (I have used a slider to adjust the value) .The problem was solved by applying a loading controller of ionic framework. 
**You need to give time to complete the response and render before the final display**.

Hope it will help you.

[image: line graph with wrong order]